# python conditional formatting replace

Tags: python-3.7

I have a table with column names for a current month and next 24 months:
i.e. col_tier1, col_tier1_mo1, col_tier_mo2...col_tier_mo24

and I have a list which I am formatting for an update where col_tier1_mo1 = col_tier1, col_tier2_mo = col_tier1_mo ....

having an issue getting format correct for the first line where there is no "mo_"

```
cols24mo_tiers = [
    "col_tier1",
    "col_tier2"
]
```

the formatting string

```py
    for col_prefix in cols24mo_tiers:
        monthly_cols.extend(["{0}{1} = {0}{2}".format(col_prefix, str(i+1), str(i) if i > 0 else '') for i in range(24)])
```

thought I could do something like this but python doesn't like it

```py
for col_prefix in cols24mo_tiers:
        monthly_cols.extend(["{0}{1} = {0}{2}".format(if i > 0 col_prefix+"mo_" else col_prefix, str(i+1), str(i) if i > 0 else '') for i in range(24)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it, but you mixed up the order for the first `if` in the argument list to `.format`. You had `if i > 0 col_prefix+"mo_" else col_prefix` when it should be `col_prefix+"mo_" if i > 0 else col_prefix` (for the later `if` with `str(i)`, you have it correct). That whole block should then be

```py
for col_prefix in cols24mo_tiers:
    monthly_cols.extend(["{0}{1} = {0}{2}".format(col_prefix + "mo_" if i > 0 else col_prefix, str(i+1), str(i) if i > 0 else '') for i in range(24)])
```

Comment: Nathan, that worked for the most part but am still getting this on the first line of output,   col_tier11 = col_tier1, I'd want that to be col_tier1_mo1 = col_tier1